# SQL select only one row (with all attibute values) of each different value

Tags: sql, oracle

in SQL Developer, i want to select only one row from my table (with all attibute values) of each different value.
It's not important what row is selected for each type, what matters is to select only one row for type.

for example i have this table:

```
| A |  B  | C |
  X    SS   G
  Y    SB   T
  Z    SB   T
```

Note that in my table there aren't numbers.

The result i want is:

```
| A |  B  | C |
  X    SS   G
  Z    SB   T
```

But is correct also

```
| A |  B  | C |
  X    SS   G
  Y    SB   T
```

Thank you!

Comment: Type of what?  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what you want. You could get your result just with

```
Select distinct top 2 * from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You want only 1 row from the rows with `c = 'T'`, right?

```
select a, b, c from tablename where c <> 'T'
union all
select a, b, c from (
  select a, b, c from tablename where c = 'T'
) where rownum <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below if the value of A is not important

```
SELECT max(A) as A,B,C FROM your_table GROUP BY B,C
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all for your answers, but I solved in this way:

```
SELECT MAX(A), B, MAX(C)
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY B;
```

With this query I can extract all values for each different type of B.
I hope this will be helpful for someone.